# why does that navigation bar is transparent?

Tags: vue.js

when i scroll down the page, the navigation bar sticks on the top and later on part keeps going up,but it is going through the navigation bar.
it looks like navigation bar is transparent.

code https://codepen.io/manpreetwadhoun/pen/LvMjBY

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>1st</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1 >head</h1> 
    <header >
      <ul  id="listContainer">
        <li >
          <a href="#">Home</a>

        </li> 
        <li >
          <a  href="#">About</a></li> 
        <li >
          <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li >
          <a href="#">Order Online</a></li>

      </ul>

    </header>

  <section>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="home- 
 dish">

  </section>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used a huge image that covers a large area of the screen below. The natural background color of the `document root` is white, unless a background color is specified on an element, such as `html` or `body`.

The white is just an illusion here.

Simply add the background color to your header:

```
header {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Now you have that persistent background that you want.

Comment: yeah i did that and but i was looking for the reason. thank you so much for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you should simply add the following styles to the header element

```
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
```